# how to use transaction manager in spring 3

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i tried using this in spring 3 xml file but it gives error

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

what thinga are required for this to work

Comment: Please post the errors that you get and other relevant xml snippet. It will assist in providing you with a better answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a transactionManager, e.g.,

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Which requires a SessionFactory which in turn requires a DataSource (here c3p0):

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />   
  ... 
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   ...
</bean>
```

You also need to declare your transactions. I personally prefer the [declarative transaction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) approach where you simply annotate your database routines with [@Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar aopalliance-1.0.jar to your classpath and add xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx to your applicationContext.xml definition